# How to find the relative importance of input variables in a linear regression when at least one of the input variables is categorical?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, categorical-data, linear-model

I learnt that if we perform regression after normalizing/standardizing the numerical input variables the coefficients give the relative importance. What if we have both categorical factors and numerical variables as inputs.

For example - If we predict marks_in_exam from gender,iq_score,attendance 
how can we find the relative importance of gender,iq_score,attendance in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You may create 2 linear regression models (one for each gender) and see if the coefficients of the 2 models are so different then you may consider the gender to be a relevant variable for your model.
Another solution would be to binarize the gender variable and then apply linear regression.

Comment: Thanks for the response but when can i say gender has more impact than say IQ score?